# Calculate sample size for regression / experiment

Tags: r, regression, experiment-design, sample-size, statistical-power

I want to measure the dependency of voltage against temperature and humidity: `V ~ rH + T`.

The humidity will be at `rH = {10 %, 40 %, 70 %}` and the temperature at `T = {5 °C, 10 °C, 15 °C, 20 °C, 25 °C, 30 °C, 35 °C, 40 °C}`.

I've seen the `pwr.f2.test` in R:

```
pwr.f2.test(
              u = 2
              , v = NULL
              , f2 = "large"
              , sig.level = 0.05
              , power = 0.8
              )
```

to calculate the sample size which is `27.7`. I chose "`large`" for `f2` as I think the alternative hypothesis (there is a dependency) and the null hypothesis (there is none) are very different.
I've got one question now:

What exactly is the sample size representing here? Do I have to measure with 27 probes at each data point `rH_i, T_i`? Because this would be an insane experiment lasting over months.

Comment: `27.7+u` is the total sample size. Using this test you only input `u` which is the number of predictors, however you cannot include your design, how many levels for each variable. Since your are using discrete levels for a continuous variable you may have to use a power test for ANOVA or similar.

Comment: thanks a lot for the input! You raised a good aspect: I can't consider whether I'm just studying at T=(10 °C, 20 °C) or at T=(1 °C, 2 °C, 3 °C, ... 100 °C), or?

Comment: and sample size means in this context, I need to measure ~30 times at each single measurement point?

Comment: 1) Yes, you cannot include number of levels of your variable, not with this f2 test. 2) No, 30 is the total sample size, there are no measurement points in this test, hence why this may not be the best test for you.

Comment: ok, thank you! But with pwr.anova.test I also can't consider levels, or? In my case, I want to measure one single liquid, is this one group? Or would it be 3 * 8 as I have three levels at rH and eight at T?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use simulation to estimate the sample size. Take a look at [simr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/index.html).